# Having trouble checking if an array is sorted using recursion

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, recursion

This is the question : An array is sorted (in ascending order) if each element of the array is less than or equal to the next element.

Write a boolean-valued method named isSorted that accepts an integer array, and the number of elements in the array and returns whether the array is sorted.

Before showing the code : my logic is that an if else-if and else statement should first determine if the size of the array is 0,1,or 2. This is because when the size equals 1 or 2, the program must break. When the size is larger than 2, the program should check arr[size-1] > arr[size-2] and then call the method again with size decremented if that is true and just return false if it is untrue. When I ran that program, the following 2 tests failed : [1,3,2,4] and [2,1,2,3,4]. Because of this I specified that when the size is equal to 2, the method returns false if arr[0] > arr[1] however it didn't work. What am I doing wrong? I don't want to just look up the answer because I am studying for a test so I am sorry if there are repeated answers.

I know the loop is better I just wanted to study recursion

```
public boolean isSorted(int[] arr, int size) { 


    if(size == 0 || size == 1) { 

         return true; 

    } else if (size == 2) { //this is the part I don't get. 

        if (arr[0] > arr[1]) { 

            return false; 

        } else { 

             isSorted(arr,size-1); 
             return true;   

        }


    } else {

         if (arr[size-1] < arr[size-2]) { 

             return false;  

         } else { 

            isSorted(arr, size-1); 
            return true; 

         }

    }

}
```

Comment: There is not restriction in the posted task that you have to use recursion to solve the task. Using simple for loop actually is better approach

Answer (score 3):

Recursion is not good way to solve this problem. What if your array will be very big and you could get `StackOverflowError`. Why not to use simple `if` operator:

```
public static boolean isSorted(int[] arr, int size) {
    if (arr.length >= 2)
        for (int i = 1; i < arr.length; i++)
            if (arr[i - 1] > arr[i])
                return false;

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need return the result from `isSorted`, for example, change:

```
isSorted(arr, size-1); 
return true;
```

to

```
return isSorted(arr, size-1);
```

---

And, the case `else if (size == 2)` is redundant. `size 2` should have the same logic with `size 3, 4, 5, ...`

---

Complete code:

```
public boolean isSorted(int[] arr, int size) {
    if (size == 0 || size == 1) {
        return true;
    } else {
        if (arr[size - 1] < arr[size - 2]) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return isSorted(arr, size - 1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, can you explain why we have to have a separate else if statement for when the size equals 2?

Comment: @Person No, it's redundant. When the size is 2, it has the same logic with size 3, 4, 5, ...

Comment: Seems the `size == 0` condition is redundant as well

Comment: @Maxim It's a corner case. When the original array's length is 0.

Comment: @Person You might want to learn how to use a debugger. It helps a lot. You can debug with IDEs such as Eclipse, IntelliJ IDEA.